# can I use sed or an equivalent to cleanup vala generated files?

Tags: bash, shell, vala

The release tarball from the maintainer for [this project](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/releases) contains vala generated c files.

I'm looking for a solution to look for the .vala files and remove the equivalent .c file

For example

```
directory\file1.vala
directory\file1.c
directory\file3.c
directory\subdirectory\file2.vala
directory\subdirectory\file2.c
directory\subdirectory\file4.c
```

From the above I want to delete file1.c and file2.c but not file3.c and file4.c

So reaching for the trusty `find` I can use

```
find . -name "*.vala" -exec ls {} \;
```

This will list all vala files.

Going slightly further I can change the output to .c via

```
find . -name "*.vala" | sed -e 's/.vala/.c/'
```

Now I need to go one step further and delete those .c files.

I suppose I could redirect the output into another file and then write a shell script to loop round each line and delete the file.

Any thoughts on a better way?  Is there a better way to clean up vala generated files?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by cleaning up the generated .c files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append this to your sed command:

```
| xargs echo rm -v
```

If everything looks okay remove `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

Cyrus' recommendation to use xargs is probably more appropriate, but if your find supports `-exec ... +` you can also use:

```
find . -name "*.vala" -exec bash -c 'echo ${@/vala/c}' sh {} +
find . -name "*.vala" -exec bash -c 'rm ${@/vala/c}' sh {} +
```

(You can use `\;` as well as `+`, but the extra shell invocations will make it pretty slow if you have a lot of files. )  Note that this is equivalent to your sed and suffers from the same problem as the sed solution in handling files with names like `avala.vala`.